# how do td value of a textbox using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get a value from `<td>` and assign that value into a textbox. I am able to get the value from `<td>` but unable to assign it to textbox.

```
var aggrName=document.getElementById ('staticid').innerHTML;    
$('#editvpa').val(aggrName);
```

Tried the above code but doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: add html mark up

Comment: You're mixing `JavaScript` with `jQuery`. Also, to be able to help you we need to see the `HTML` too

Comment: Do you want td with id 'staticid' text to be assigned into textbox with id 'editvpa'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<table border=1>

  <tr>
    <td id="staticid">123</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="text" id="getVal">

var val = $('#staticid').text();
$('#getVal').val(val);
```

Fiddler https://jsfiddle.net/1m1hzqem/1/

Comment: You just copied the answer someone else gave earlier and deleted it because the OP hadn't add the `HTML` code.

Comment: Don't you think the OP should put some effort in his question before it can be answered?

Comment: @TariqJaved How do you know OP has html you have used in your answer? Without original markup this question simply can't be answered.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
var aggrName=document.getElementById ('staticid').innerHTML;  
document.getElementById ('textbox_id').value = aggrName;
```

where `textbox_id` is id associated to your textbox.